# embed a video with embedly in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, embedly

I try to use embedly in my rails 3.2 application.
I register on embed.ly and have my key that I put in my application.js like this :

```
$.embedly.defaults.key = 'mykeycodexxxxxxxxxxxxx';
```

I have a field @mean.link that I would like to embed
I look about embedly-ruby and embedly-jquery but I was not able to add nothing working. Perhaps because I'm not familiar with jquery or javascript and only with rails ?

Sorry for the very newbie's question

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking for.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to use embedly with my rails app. The documentation or gems or questions/responses here don't gave me any solution to include their api.

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: 
    
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28622912/using-embedly-with-rails

Answer (score 0):

Just add `gem 'embedly'` and run bundle install. then set `require 'embedly'` in your controller and initialiser/application.rb then add key in your view like

```
<%embedly_api = Embedly::API.new :key => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'%>
<%=obj[0].marshal_dump %>
```

and require 'rails/all'
require 'embedly'
require 'json'
 to config/application.rb
thats it you may also follow https://github.com/embedly/embedly-ruby...enjoy coding.